# Laravel, function create and edit, retrieve data from tags

Tags: php, laravel, tags

I have a basic article and tag system, with a Many to Many relationship. I manage to display all tags in the create function but I don’t know how to display all tags and tags checked in the edit function.

**Article :**

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Tag :**

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

**function create :**

```
public function create()
{
    $article = new Article();
    $tags = $article->tags = Tag::all();
    return view('articles.create', compact('article','tags'));
}
```

**function edit**

```
public function edit(Article $article)
{
    return view('articles.edit', compact('article'));
}
```

**form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @foreach($article->tags as $tag)
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="{{ $tag->id }}" /> {{ $tag->name }}</label>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

really need help pls, it’s for a school project. and sorry for my english...
create: 
[screen for add an article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se1pw.png)
edit : 
[screen for edit an article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQFr8.png)

Comment: How are you establishing a relationship between your tags and articles?do you have a pivot table like `article_tag`?

Comment: hello, Yes, I do, everything works i can,  I can display all the articles with their tags. Actually the inly problem is, I can’t get 'checked' on the checkboxes. in the edit function.

Comment: The tags are shown in the edit view as well?

Comment: yes, show only unchecked tags associated with each articles.

Comment: Please clarify. On the edit page, do you want to show tags with check-mark and/or just list of tags that are not associated with the article?

Comment: well check-mark and entire list.

Comment: On edit page, the way you're doing it now, you're just showing ALL tags (`$tags = $article->tags = Tag::all();`) not only that article’s tags and that's why you see them on edit page but not on create. I think the problem relies in your relationships..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I found it ! just needed a second foreach

```
@foreach ($tags as $tag)
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="{{ $tag->id }}"
      @foreach ($article->tags as $article_tags)
        {{ $article_tags->id == $tag->id ? 'checked' : '' }}
      @endforeach>{{ $tag->name }}</label>
@endforeach
```

and in the create `$tags= Tag::all();`

thanks for the help anyway ^^